# Is it possible for a Generic to be optional and nil?

Tags: swift, generics

I was trying to print my output form the API on the console for debugging purposes.
I have this method that I planned on calling in both cases, for error and success.

```
private static func printDetail<T>(route: APIRouter, resultSuccess: T? = nil, resultError: Any? = nil) where T: Codable {
    let isSuccess = resultSuccess != nil

    isSuccess ? print("✅✅✅✅✅✅") : print("❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌")

    // FOR Debuging Purposes
    print("----------------")
    print("REQUEST")
    print("----------------")

    print("PATH : --> " + route.fullPath)

    print("parameters : --> ")
    print((route.parameters ?? "none"))

    print("methods : --> ")
    print((route.method.rawValue))

    print("Headears : --> ")
    print((route.allHeaders))

    print("----------------")
    print("Response")
    print("----------------")

    if isSuccess {
        let json = try! getJson(model: resultSuccess!)
        print(json)
    } else {
        print(resultError!)
    }

    print("----------------")

    isSuccess ? print("✅✅✅✅✅✅") : print("❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌")
}
```

So I called this for the success case and it worked as I expected.

```
// For Simplicity assume value is any Generic
// let value: (T)


self.printDetail(route: route, resultSuccess: value)
```

But for the Error case, I can't just pass the generic nil.

```
self.printDetail(route: route, resultError: jsonResult)
```

I get this error

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Which is pretty understandable, so my question is there anything that can be done to use the same method using Generic? Can Generic be optional and nil in this scenario? or the only option I've is to make two different methods for Error and Success cases.

Comment: Do you really need the Generic in this case? What about using `Any?` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even `nil` can be cast into optional type which should suffice for you. If I understand your question correctly you want it like so:

```
func printDetail<SuccessType, ErrorType>(route: APIRouter, resultSuccess: SuccessType? = nil, resultError: ErrorType? = nil) where SuccessType: Codable {
```

Now if you try and call the following you will receive an error as you describe:

```
printDetail(route: route, resultSuccess: nil, resultError: nil) // Generic parameter 'ErrorType' could not be inferred
```

But if you simply cast your `nil` objects:

```
printDetail(route: route, resultSuccess: nil as String?, resultError: nil as String?)
```

All should work fine. This way you give your compiler a hint on types and that is all it needs.